# Type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId' is not supported for identity members

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, orm, hierarchyid

I'm getting the above exception while trying to read data from a table using Linq2Sql. Does anyone know what's happening here?

Comment: Not used this but thinking laterally, could this be because identity members are auto generated?

Comment: Not in this case they're not.

Comment: SqlHierarchyId is an odd duck. It is a struct and is only binary serializable and I have found it to not play well with others.